# Unable to resolve host "My URL" - No address associated with hostname

Tags: java, android, exception, android-asynctask

The exception occurs randomly and then its hard to get rid of. I am tired of this error and despite the fact that I have tried almost everything on stackoverflow from changing url to respective IP address, using real device, adding internet permissions as mentioned or checking wifi connection. Everything is all right except the error which keeps coming back. Yes I also added checking connection code as below :

```
try {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext()

                    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

            if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting()) {

                URL url = new URL(urlx);
                HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();
                urlc.setConnectTimeout(1000); // mTimeout is in seconds

                urlc.connect();

                if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            //Do something on UiThread
                            upsuccess = true;
                        }
                    });
                } else {

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            //Do something on UiThread
                            upsuccess = false;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and `System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "myurl.com");
                    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");`

but each of them separately as well as together did not fetch me any useful results. Can you suggest me what to do?

I am basically doing this : I am uploading a pdf file on my server and loading the google docs viewer url with that url. I however see the following exception several times. I also added retrying in case I find the exception but the exception randomly happens and is not easy to get out of if you encounter it.

Exception :

> java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "myurl.com": No
>   address associated with hostname 07-20 01:12:11.554
>   24907-24997/securitymsg.listmydocs W/System.err:     at
>   java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:95)
>   07-20 01:12:11.554 24907-24997/securitymsg.listmydocs W/System.err:
>   at
>   java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:74)
>   07-20 01:12:11.554 24907-24997/securitymsg.listmydocs W/System.err:
>   at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:752) 07-20
>   01:12:11.554 24907-24997/securitymsg.listmydocs W/System.err:     at
>   okhttp3.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39) 07-20 01:12:11.554
>   24907-24997/securitymsg.listmydocs W/System.err:     at
>   okhttp3.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:173)
>   07-20 01:12:11.554 24907-24997/securitymsg.listmydocs W/System.err:
>   at
>   okhttp3.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:139)
>   07-20 01:12:11.554 24907-24997/securitymsg.listmydocs W/System.err:
>   at okhttp3.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:81)
>   07-20 01:12:11.554 24907-24997/securitymsg.listmydocs W/System.err:
>   at
>   okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:172)
>   07-20 01:12:11.554 24907-24997/securitymsg.listmydocs W/System.err:
>   at
>   okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:123)
>   07-20 01:12:11.554 24907-24997/securitymsg.listmydocs W/System.err:
>   at
>   okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:93)
>   07-20 01:12:11.554 24907-24997/securitymsg.listmydocs W/System.err:
>   at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:296) 07-20
>   01:12:11.554 24907-24997/securitymsg.listmydocs W/System.err:     at
>   okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
>   07-20 01:12:11.554 24907-24997/securitymsg.listmydocs W/System.err:
>   at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponse(RealCall.java:243) 07-20 01:12:11.554
>   24907-24997/securitymsg.listmydocs W/System.err:     at
>   okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:201)
>   07-20 01:12:11.554 24907-24997/securitymsg.listmydocs W/System.err:
>   at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:163)
>   07-20 01:12:11.554 24907-24997/securitymsg.listmydocs W/System.err:
>   at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:57) 07-20 01:12:11.554
>   24907-24997/securitymsg.listmydocs W/System.err:     at
>   securitymsg.listmydocs.CloudViewer$UploadFileAsync.doInBackground(CloudViewer.java:678)
>   07-20 01:12:11.554 24907-24997/securitymsg.listmydocs W/System.err:
>   at
>   securitymsg.listmydocs.CloudViewer$UploadFileAsync.doInBackground(CloudViewer.java:650)
>   07-20 01:12:11.554 24907-24997/securitymsg.listmydocs W/System.err:
>   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305) 07-20 01:12:11.554
>   24907-24997/securitymsg.listmydocs W/System.err:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 07-20
>   01:12:11.554 24907-24997/securitymsg.listmydocs W/System.err:     at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 07-20
>   01:12:11.554 24907-24997/securitymsg.listmydocs W/System.err:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>   07-20 01:12:11.554 24907-24997/securitymsg.listmydocs W/System.err:
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>   07-20 01:12:11.554 24907-24997/securitymsg.listmydocs W/System.err:
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 07-20 01:12:13.016
>   24907-24907/securitymsg.listmydocs W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call
>   determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 24907
>   07-20 01:12:13.677 24907-24907/securitymsg.listmydocs
>   W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a
>   connection for the pid: 24907 07-20 01:12:13.678
>   24907-24907/securitymsg.listmydocs W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call
>   determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 24907

My Permissions in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

My code to upload file :

*PHP :

```
<?php

$file_path = "images/";

$neran = $_GET['neran'];
 $ext = pathinfo(basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$file_path = "images/".$neran.".".$ext;
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path) ){
    echo "success";
} else{
    echo "fail";
}
```

?>

Android side (I use Retrofit) : The following code is in doinbackground block of AsyncTask

```
String file_path = f.getAbsolutePath();
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        RequestBody file_body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(content_type),f);
        Log.e("msh", content_type);
        RequestBody request_body = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("type",content_type)
                .addFormDataPart("uploaded_file",file_path.substring(file_path.lastIndexOf("/")+1), file_body)
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://reviewitapp.co/retrofit_example/save_file.php?neran="+neran)
                .post(request_body)
                .build();



            response = client.newCall(request).execute();



        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            /*uploadFile(selectedFilePath);*/
            upsuccess = false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            upsuccess = false;
        }  catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            /*uploadFile(selectedFilePath);*/
            upsuccess = false;
        }

        if(response!=null) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                upsuccess = true;
            }
            response.body().close();
        }
```

Comment: myurl.com not returns a web page use a valid url, you can see go to your browser and type the myurl.com.

Comment: @BrunoFerreira That is just a placeholder. I do not want to share my website URL here. However, if it helps you answer my question then the URL is reviewitapp.co. Thanks!

Comment: I typed the url in my browser and it says that the url is incorrect, if you type the url in your browser it return a website?

Comment: @BrunoFerreira Did you type it correctly? I checked again and its opening fine. It should be returning a website with "Aptile" logo on the top left corner. The api for uploading however is in subfolders. I will edit and add the code I use to upload file as well.

Comment: My bad i typed correctly now and return a website now.

Comment: you can try read this links, if you are using retrofit 1 https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-how-to-upload-files/, and if your are using retrofit 2 https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server

Comment: @BrunoFerreira The files are uploading just fine using retrofit most of the times. However, it gives me the exception that I just mentioned in the post randomly at certain times without a clear reason. This issue is not limited to retrofit but has been an issue when I used this code instead : http://www.coderefer.com/android-upload-file-to-server/